# How do you trigger the evaluation of a mail method using RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, rspec

```
class MyMailer < BaseMailer
  def send_login_prompt
    User.reset_login
    # ...
  end
end

describe MyMailer do
  context "when sending a login prompt" do
    it "should reset the user's password" do
      expect(User).to receive(:reset_login)
      MyMailer.send_login_prompt
    end
  end
end
```

### The incarnation of the test above fails

In the example above we've got a mailer method that triggers a user's password to be
reset. We want to test for that. However when you run the test, `.send_login_prompt`
does not get called.

In order to actually trigger the code to be evaluated you have to add a line to
inspect the mail object:

### Test that works

```
it "should reset the user's password" do
  expect(User).to receive(:reset_login)
  mail = MyMailer.send_login_prompt
  mail.body # after this line is added the mail is built and the test passes
end
```

Why is the method not called before and what's the most correct way to prompt the 
method to be evaluated rather than the ad-hoc route of calling `mail.body`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mail is not delivered until you access it's content or you can one of  the `.deliver` functions.

This should get the job done nicely

```
mail = MyMailer.send_login_prompt.deliver_now
```